# How do you say the order of magnitude related to a specific value?

Tags: mathematics, quantifiers

I have to explain a range of measures affecting a specific value, so I think writing this sentence:

> response time is limited to units of second in order of magnitude

Is it correct?

Comment: Just to make sure: you mean that, roughly speaking, the response time won't be more than 10 seconds or less than 0.1 seconds?

Comment: Some extra context would be helpful.

Comment: Response time is related to an interactive application, so it's a way to inform about which range of values you may detect in that system. Nathan's interval agree with my aim.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a bit weird for me to use order of magnitude in this context. I'd more likely write

> response time is a matter of seconds

In my opinion, `order of magnitude` should rather be used in comparision, such as `The power output of our new device exceeds yours by several orders of magnitude`.